# Yii2 model validation message from the label assigned via ActiveForm

Tags: validation, yii2, active-form

Is there any way to prompt for validation with the attribute's label assigned via `ActiveForm`?
For instance I have a model attribute `amount` and the label defined in its `attributeLabels` function is "Amount"
But while generating form I neeed the label "Fees" so:
`$form->field($model, 'amount')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('Fees')`
After validation it prompts me "Amount cannot be blank" - it is known to me that we can write a rule to change message but according to my requirements, same attribute (from same model) is having different labels on different forms.
I know that back-end implementation of default message uses:
`'message' => '{attribute} cannot be blank.'` does anyone know if there is any `{x}` by which the assigned label in ActiveForm can be retrieved?
PS: I know that this problem can be resolved by scenarios. But it would be hectic to write rule for every field which has dual label.

Comment: Hey mate! If one of the two answers helped you out, you should mark it as such...for other users to find :)!

Comment: Marked. Thanks for reminding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such way, sorry! What you are doing is overriding the label within the view. Actually within the form to be more precise. If you check out what the `label()`-method [does](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/widgets/ActiveField.php#L258), you will see that it calls `activeLabel()` from the [Html-helper](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseHtml.php#L1109). This method in turn renders your label and returns the code.

As you can see, none of this information gets written back to the model. Therefore, during the validation process, you won't have your new label at hand, because it never makes its way into the model.

Your cleanest option is the one you mentioned already. Use scenarios to decide which validation rule (and therefore message) to use. OR you could create your own public property in which you write your temporary label like so:

```
class MyModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $myTempLabel;

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        $myLabel = $this->myTempLabel === null ? Yii::t('app', 'defaultLabel') : $this->myTempLabel;

        return [
            //other labels...
            'myField'=>$myLabel,
            //other labels...
        ];
    }
}
```

In your view you can then set the value back into the attribute within your model.

Sorry for not being able to help better, but that's the way it's implemented!

Comment: wow that was a great explanation (Y) I usually go through core implementation, but I don't know how did i forgot this time. Thanks, you made it a-lot easier for me to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is handle the label changing logic in your attributeLabels() function.

```
class MyModel extends \yii\base\Model {

  public $amount_label = 'amount';

  public function attributeLabels() {
    return [
       'amount' => $this->amount_label
    ];
  }
}
```

Then in your controller.

```
$model = new MyModel;
$model->amount_label = 'fees';
...
```

Of course you may want to set the label in a different way.  For example, if your model as a type attribute, and this is the attribute which determines the label, you could do a conditional based on that type attribute.

Comment: just a correction: try to keep exceptions in mind :) what if someone doesn't set `$model->amount_label` and the attribute get used by ActiveForm? Obviously the application would crash. you could do it like: `'amount' => empty($this->amount_label) ? 'default_label' : $this->amount_label`